# Problem related to tachyon particles

Tags: special-relativity, faster-than-light, tachyon

Are [Tachyons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tachyon) practically possible to exist? if they are how can we harness them?
I have already tried finding answers but none are satisfactory. please help.